# Can I use only one stream expression to get the result with two condition in JDK8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Here is my code,but I find that it is not good.Can I use  only one stream expression to get the result with two condition in JDK8 ?I want to make sure that id conditon is first and name condition is second.

```
  public Student getStudent(String id,String name)  {
    try {
        List<Student> students = studentDao.getStudent();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(students)) {
            Student studentDomain=students.stream()
                    .filter(p -> id .equals(p.getId()))
                    .findAny().orElse(null);
            if(studentDomain==null){
                studentDomain=students.stream()
                        .filter(p -> name.equals(p.getName()))
                        .findAny()
                        .orElse(null);
            }
            return studentDomain;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){ 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you figure that? the second is only done if the first (in total) returns null. if you combine them, and the first it finds is the result of the second, you risk getting an invalid result.

Comment: You can filter on either and then sort on `!id.equals(p.getId())` but I'm not sure it'll be more readable or efficient.

Comment: *`catch (Exception ex) { return null; }`* — Please don't do this. You are suppressing *all* potential exceptions, including `NullPointerException`s, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s and all other `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: @MCEmperor,NullPointerExceptions ??

Comment: @Rebecca Yes, for example if `studentDao`, `studentDao.getStudent()`, `id` or `name` is `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams should not be overused, sometimes it makes sense to get back to loops.
In your case `foreach` would be simpler and nicer. Something like (pseudocode):

```
Student res;

for (Student s : students) {
    if s.id == id -> { res = s; break; }
    if s.name == name -> res = s;
}
```

Comment: If the id of the first student doesn't match this loop would end.

Comment: I said this is pseudocode ;)

Comment: Yes, but even pseudocode has to convey some logic. Op asks to search for the name again, if a search for the id wasn't successfull. This implies two searches i.e. two loops. I have made the same mistake.

Comment: we can search for both at the same time; if id matches we exit, if name matches we take it, so if no id match, we will be left with a name match; and if none match - we have null

Comment: Imagine you have the list: [(5, Jack), (6, Jack)] and you would search for id: 6, name: Jack. Your code would return the first one.

Comment: not really, there is no break after the name matches

Comment: God, you're right.

Comment: just one thing: this will search till the end for the matching name, but this is up to the OP if this is the behavior they expect

Comment: Op used findAny() in their approach which suggests that this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Checked it again, sorry. With prioritized id you have to check twice. Which justifies another method:

```
public Student getStudent(String id, String name) {
    try {
        List<Student> students = studentDao.getStudent();
        Student studentDomain = find(students, s -> id.equals(s.getId()));
        return studentDomain != null 
                                ? studentDomain 
                                : find(students, s -> name.equals(s.getName()));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

static <T> T find(Collection<T> l, Predicate<T> p) {
    return l.stream().filter(p).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to prioritize `id` matches.

Comment: try to use Optional.ofNullable(xxx) to replace the condition

Comment: Id equals and name not equal is the right result.

Comment: Sorry, i misread the question. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot do it in **one single** stream. In one stream one could keep a matched name as side effect and check the id. But that is ugly.

In this case you have to check all students for an `id` and failing that, for a `name`, again over all students.

When reaching the end of a Stream you cannot skip back to the beginning - in the same stream.

However it would be beneficial to have a Map from `id` to `Student`.

When there is a `Optional<Student> StudentDao#findById`:

```
return studentDao.findById(id)
```

When there is (an inferiaor) `<Student> StudentDao#findById`:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(studentDao.findById(id))
```

You need only search by name:

```
    .orElseGet(() -> studentDao.getStudent().stream()
                    .filter(p -> name.equals(p.getName()))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
```

The best would be to leave filtering by name to the StudentDao.

Also a better practice would be

```
public Optional<Student> getStudent(String id, String name)  {


getStudent("6534266", "Joe").ifPresent(student -> ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8 you can use the following approach:

```
public Student getStudent(String id,String name)  {

    List<Student> students = studentDao.getStudent();
    
    return students.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.getId().equals(id))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> students.stream()
            .filter(student -> student.getName().equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null)
        );
}
```

I've ignored your attempt to catch a `Exception`. Firstly, never super-types `Exception` and `Throwable`, your catch blocks should target a specific exception. And never catch runtime exceptions, unless you're not performing some kind of actions (like to undo partial changes made in the `try` block) and then propagating (throwing from the `catch`) this exception further.

In case if you expect the list of student returned by `studentDao.getStudent()` to be `null`, it would be way cleaner to make it return an *empty list* by default instead of clattering your code with defensive `null`-checks everywhere you use it.

Do you expect that elements in the collection of students would be `null`? Well, that an antipattern - never store `null` in the collection.

***Note*** that returning `null` from `getStudent` makes sense **only** if you have a code calling this method which consumes `null` (makes `null`-checks) and which **can not** be changed. Otherwise - leverage the boons of Java 8 to full power, return `Optional<Student>`.

Here's the possible solution for Java 9 (method `or()` was introduced with Java 9) returning `Optional<Student>`:

```
public Optional<Student> getStudent(String id,String name)  {
    
    List<Student> students = studentDao.getStudent();
    
    return students.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.getId().equals(id))
        .findFirst()
        .or(() -> students.stream()
            .filter(student -> student.getName().equals(name))
            .findFirst()
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a mutable result container which collects the results, prioritizing any found `id` over any found `name`.

First, let's define such a result container:

```java
public class OrderedKeyMatcher<T> {

    private int predicateLevel;
    private T result;
    private final List<Predicate<T>> predicates;

    public OrderedKeyMatcher(Predicate<T>... predicates) {
        this.predicates = List.of(predicates);
        this.predicateLevel = predicates.length;
    }

    public OrderedKeyMatcher<T> accept(T t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < predicateLevel; i++) {
            if (predicates.get(i).test(t)) {
                predicateLevel = i;
                result = t;
                break;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isDefinitelyFound() {
        return predicateLevel == 0;
    }

    public Optional<T> result() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }
}
```

In short, this is how it works:

- In that order, the `predicates` field holds the predicates to which the students are tested.
- The `result` field holds any found student.
- The `predicateLevel` holds an integer, which keeps track of *what* predicate matched the last result. This is because of the following: if we found a student with the given `name`, we don't need to search any further for students with the given name, because we already found one; **however**, we still want to try to find a student with the given `id`.
- Further, if a student is matched by the *first* predicate, we can tell the stream to stop altogether because we have *definitely found* a student matching or predicates. The `isDefinitelyFound()` method can be used for this.

This is then what the stream looks like:

```java
var matcher = new OrderedKeyMatcher<Student>(
    s -> Objects.equals(s.id(), id),
    s -> Objects.equals(s.name(), name)
);

Optional<Student> optStudent = studentDao.getStudent().stream()
    .takeWhile(unused -> !matcher.isDefinitelyFound())
    .reduce(matcher, OrderedKeyMatcher::accept, (a, b) -> a)
    .result();
```

- `takeWhile` is used to short-circuit the stream if a result is found. As noted above, if we find a student with a matching name, then we still need to inspect other elements to see if there's a student with a matching *id*, but once we find a student with a matching id, then we can tell the stream to terminate.
- `reduce` collects the elements into our result container.<sup>1</sup>
- At last, with `result()` we can collect the result as an `Optional`.

#### Example

Let's take a look at the following list:

```java
List.of(
    new Student("11", "John"),
    new Student("13", "Jill"),
    new Student("17", "Jack"),
    new Student("17", "Anthony"),
    new Student("23", "Bonnie"),
    new Student("47", "Megan")
);
```

Suppose we are trying to match `id = "23"` and `name = "Jack"`. The expected *and* actual result is that we'll find student Bonnie because she has id 23. Now let's say we'll remove Bonnie from the list, and search again. The result is that we find Jack.

---

<sup>1. Note that I used `(a, b) -> a` as a merge function, which is, of course, a dummy merge function, as it drops at least half of the results.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility by library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
StreamEx.of(student).findFirstOrAny(p -> id.equals(p.getId()), p -> name.equals(p.getName());
```

Not sure which db access library you're using for `studentDao`, There is another library [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc) created based on `abacus-common`. It provides the Stream apis for Dao:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //......
}

......

public interface StudentDao extends CrudDao<Student, Long, SQLBuilder.PSC, StudentDao>  {
    // no implementation required.
}

......
static final StudentDao studentDao = JdbcUtil.createDao(StendentDao.class, dataSouce);

......
long id = 123;
String name = "xyz";
// if student queried by condition: eq("id", 123).or("name", name)
Optional<Student> result = studentDao.stream(eq("id", 123).or(eq("name", name)))
                                 .findFirstOrAny(p -> p.getId() == id);

// Or by other condition:
result = studentDao.stream(cond)
    .findFirstOrAny(p -> p.getId() == id, p -> name.equals(p.getName());
```

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of `abacus-common` and `abacus-jdbc`.